# Extract files from stream containing zip

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am making a GET request using HttpClient to download a zip file from the internet.
I want to extract all the files contained in the zip file without saving the zip file to disk.
Currently, I am able to download and save the zip file to disk, extract its contents and then delete the zip file from disk. This perfectly fine. However, I want to optimize the process.
I found a way to extract the contents directly from the downloaded zip stream but I have to specify the filenames and extensions.
I am not sure how to extract the contents while preserving their original filenames and extensions without me specifying them.

Current Approach:

```
string requestUri = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/" + PackageName + "/" + PackageVersion;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
using Stream PackageStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
SaveStream($"{DownloadPath}.zip", PackageStream);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory($"{DownloadPath}.zip", ExtractPath);
File.Delete($"{DownloadPath}.zip");

// Directly extract Zip contents without saving file and without losing filename and extension
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
   foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
   {
       using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
       {
           using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
           {
               stream.CopyTo(file);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

.NET 4.8
.NET Core 3.1
C# 8.0

Any help in this regards would be appreciated.
Please feel free to comment on alternative approaches or suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZipArchiveEntry` has a `Name` and `FullName` property that can be used to get the  names of the files within the archive while preserving their original filenames and extensions

> The FullName property contains the relative path, including the subdirectory hierarchy, of an entry in a zip archive. (In contrast, the Name property contains only the name of the entry and does not include the subdirectory hierarchy.)

For example

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())) {
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
        using (Stream stream = entry.Open()) {                        
            string destination = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(downloadPath, entry.FullName));

            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(destination);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will extract the files in the same subdirectory hierarchy as they were stored in the archive while if `entry.Name` was used, all the files would be extracted to the same location.

Comment: How do I create directories in case they do not exist? Tried using Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadPath) but many times it throws DirectoryNotFoundException even if the directory was created in the file system

Comment: @RonakThakkar check update that includes checking for the directory before trying to save the file.